# What pointer values are well-defined to compute?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

I was under the impression that while dereferencing pointers that don't point to a valid object is UB, simply computing such pointers is fine.

However, if I'm understanding [expr.add[4]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4) correctly, that's not the case.

So which of these pointer computations are well-defined?

```
int a = 42;
int *p = &a;
p;           // valid, and obviously ok
p++;         // invalid, but ok, because one past the end of 'array' containing 1 element?
p++;         // UB ?
```

How about this case?

```
int *p = nullptr;
p;                // invalid, and obviously ok (considered one past the end?)
p++;              // one past the end? or UB?
```

Comment: Outside valid pointers, the only 2 allowed pointers are null pointer and 1 past array end. Your linked section summarizes it clearly, it seems?

Comment: @rustyx clearly enough for the 1st case, I *think*. I'm not sure about the second case though.

Comment: @rustyx See the note (76) right at the bottom of the linked page

Comment: @RichardCritten That's what my reasoning was for the 1st `p++`. Does that not apply to the 3rd case?

Comment: @cigien `nullptr` doesn't point to an object so the footnote doesn't apply?

Comment: @Artyer yeah, that seems resonable.

Comment: You have asked which are **allowed**. Not only does the C++ standard not prohibit you from doing these things, it is a voluntary standard you do not have to obey at all. The question you meant to ask is which are **defined** by the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's true, edited, thanks.

Comment: The two cases you call "invalid" are valid.  Past-the-end, and null pointers are valid pointers . (see [basic.compound]/3)

Comment: @M.M Yes, but I feel editing those particular usages now would invalidate that part of the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, the first `p++` is well-defined, because a non-array is considered a one-length array.

Here's the relevant quote ([basic.compound/3.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.4)):

> For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past the end of the last element of an array x of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array element n of x and an **object of type T that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T**.

After `p++`, `p` it will point past the last (and only) element of the (hypothetical) array, which is well-defined. It is not "invalid, but ok", as pointers pointing to past the end of an object are not invalid pointers, [basic.compound/3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.2):

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - a **pointer past the end of an object**
> - [...]
> - an invalid pointer value.

The second `p++` of the first example is UB, because the result will point after the hypothetical (&a)[1] element, which is not defined.

In your second example, `p++` is UB, because only 0 can be added to a `nullptr` ([expr.add/4.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1)):

> - If P evaluates to a **null pointer value and J evaluates to 0**, the result is a null pointer value.
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**.

Comment: Thank you! really useful information.